# "TypeError: Cannot handle this data type" when trying to make a PIL Image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

No existing answer on this issue solves my problem. I'm just trying to make an `Image` with `PIL`. Reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (32, 32, 1))

img = Image.fromarray(img)
img = np.array(img)
```

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Comment: use `(32,32)` instead of `(32,32,1)`

Comment: Yes I did see my new answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from *Image.fromarray()* and the default way it works. Since you don't specify the kind of color set the image has, the default value is None.

If you want to set that the array you are passing to it is an RGB image, you have to specify it:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (32, 32, 1)) # I recommend to set 3 instead of 1... you know... RGB...

img = Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last dimension

```
Image.fromarray(your_array[:, :, 0])
```